# In OWL, is it possible to assert that a class is not "empty"?

Tags: logic, owl, semantic-web, description-logic

Given the different types of axioms available in OWL, is it possible to assert that a class is not "empty"? Or in other words, can we assert that there exists at least one individual that is part of the specified class?

So, basically I am looking for an equivalence of:

```
ObjectAssertNotEmpty(a:SomeClass)
```

Comment: what would be the impact of such an axiom?

Comment: `a:SomeClass SubClassOf not owl:Nothing` - looks weird to me

Comment: Stating that a class is not empty is not necessary as the reasoner will assume that the class is satisfiable  (that is not empty) untill it gets evidence  to the contrary then it will mark the class as unsatisfiable- that it has to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In an RDF serialization, all it takes is to identify such an individual:

```
[] a a:SomeClass .
```

I presume the OWL syntax should be able to specify it this way:

```
ClassAssertion( a:SomeClass a:SomeIndividual )
```

It doesn't matter that you call the individual `a:SomeIndividual` here, it could very well be `owl:sameAs` any other individual. Once you state that something is in the class, it follows that the class is not empty.

Comment: Anonymous individuals can be used in OWL: `ClassAssertion( a:SomeClass _:x )` (also, you inverted the class expression and the individual). Using an IRI does not merely say "this class is not empty" (as does the first triple you mention), it additionally says "this specific named thing is in the class". Then other people can say things about this entity, which may not be according to your taste.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Thank you for the correction and additional information.

Comment: Stating that an individual belongs to a class is not enough to ensure is not empty. A reasoner can still determine  that the class has to be empty. Such a class is called unsatisfiable. See my answer for a counter example to using an individual assertion to state that a class is not empty. For a class to be not empty, it has to be satisfiable, which is what the reasoner assumes till it gets evidence to the contrary, at which point the reasoner marks the class as unsatisfiable.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse It is my understanding that when you imply a class should be empty (e.g. by making it a subclass of `owl:Nothing`), asserting that an individual is in the class is a contradiction. But isn't that what this question is about? You are right that under the open-world principle, OWL should treat every class as satisfiable first, but you still have two things to assert: assert that it's empty, or assert that an individual is in it, i.e. it's not empty. If you do both, it is a contradiction regardless of whose "fault" it is (the class's or the individual's).

Comment: In DLs there is no point to assert that a concept is equivalent to owl:Nothing, because the moment you do that you are dealing with an inconsistent ontology and normal reasoning procedures no longer apply. Moreover, inconsistent ontologies are seen as containing modelling errors. See definition p.5 of [paper](https://wasp.cs.vu.nl/sekt/dion/sekt363.pdf).

Comment: Interesting discussion though! Interesting to see how people think who are not coming from a DL background necessarily.

Answer (score -1):

That is exactly what the model theoretic underpinning of Description Logics aim to do is to assume that all concepts (or OWL classes) are not empty. When a reasoner is run over an ontology, it will give an error if a class is  found to be empty. Such a class is deemed to be unsatisfiable. That is the basis of satisfiability checking (and consistency checking, since satisfiability checking can be translated to consistency checking).

[image]
See [An introduction to Description Logics text](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/Ian.Horrocks/dlbook/about.html) for details.

Here is a simple example ontology to illustrate this:

```
Class: A
Class: NotA
    EquivalentTo: not (A)

Class: B
     EquivalentTo: A and NotA

 
Individual: b
    Types: B
```

Note that class `B` will be equivalent to `owl:Nothing` which is the empty set. Now setting individual `b` to be an instance of `B` will lead to an inconsistency with explanation as shown below.

The answer as given by @IS4 will only work if `SomeClass` is found to be satisfiable (that is not empty), otherwise the reasoner will give an inconsistency.

[image: Explanation of inconsistency]

Comment: With all due respect, your claim that concepts are not empty in DL is wrong, and the text you copy does not support this claim. Also, you should put a reference to what you quote, since saying that someone, somewhere, wrote something does not provide evidence.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann I have amended my answer to make the definition for satisfiability a bit more clear and provided an example to illustrate.